# Combine (or connect) two Kafka-Clusters

Tags: apache-kafka

I was wondering if there is a way to combine two clusters. Since this scenario is just out of curiosity I don't have a real example to explain this.

But, I was thinking about a method or functionality like Apache Connect just for Cluster -> Cluster and not Database -> Cluster.

Comment: [this](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/multi-dc-deployments/replicator/replicator-quickstart.html) might be interesting for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, MirrorMaker 2 is Cluster-Cluster implemented using Kafka Connect.

Ref:

- [Design doc](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0)
- [Conference talk - "Getting up to Speed with MirrorMaker 2"](https://www.confluent.io/resources/kafka-summit-2020/getting-up-to-speed-with-mirrormaker-2/)